# How to redirect messages generated by Perl's IO::Socket::SSL qw(debug4)?

Tags: perl, logging

I want to be able to trace an error in case it happens. So far, I'm showing the logs generated by qw(debug4) in the terminal, but I want to save them to an array and maybe to a file.

This is how I defined the log generation:

`use IO::Socket::SSL qw(debug4);`

And some log examples:

```
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:692: socket not yet connected
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:694: socket connected
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:717: ssl handshake not started
```

Comment: The `debug4` output goes to STDERR by default. You can try to redirect it to a variable or a file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example of how you can redirect STDERR to a variable:

```
use feature qw(say);
use strict;
use warnings;
use IO::Socket::SSL qw(debug4);

my $stderr;
close STDERR;
open(STDERR, ">", \$stderr ) or die "Can't reopen STDERR: $!";
my $cl = IO::Socket::SSL->new('www.google.com:443');
print $cl "GET / HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n";
say $stderr;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that was exactly what I needed. I'm also trying to get the logs generated by  a IO::Socket::INET but when writing qw(debug4) in the import I get the following message: "debug4" is not exported by the Socket module". Any clue on how I can achieve this?